# Allow letters, digits and certain characters

Tags: php

In a form a user can input some text. In the validation php I would like to check if this text includes only letters, numbers and the allowed special characters: `.,:;'"/*$@#<>&+-`

```
$pattern = '/^i';
$chars = ".,:;'\"/*$@#<>&+-";
$newString = htmlspecialchars($chars);
if (!preg_match($pattern, $chars, $text))   $error = $error . "You can use only letters, digits and [.,:;'\"/*$@#<>&+-]".'<br>';
```

The `$error` variable is sent back to the page with the form and displayed there.

Am I using the wrong pattern? No matter what I type in the input box I get the error.

Comment: Your regex is just `/^i`. That's not a valid regex.

Comment: only letters? Which only letters? Can you please provide those as a PHP string in your question?

Comment: I get what you mean. At first I thought of the characters of the English alphabet, but it would be better to allow all characters, like Ł,ß,å etc.

Comment: @erdomester Well if you're going to be like that, why not allow all characters?

Comment: @Vinit Please don't edit code in questions. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your code in English:

- Set $pattern to '/^i'
- Set $chars to your list of allowed characters
- Set $newString to the HTML-encoded version of $chars
- Match '/^i' against your list of characters and store the matches in the $text variable
- If the match fails, show an error message

Well, it should be obvious what your problem is. `/^i` is not a valid regex, and if it were it would be looking for a literal `i` at the start of the text, and that's it.

Here's what I think you meant:

```
$chars = ".:;'\"/*$@#<>&+-";
if( preg_match("([^a-zA-Z0-9".preg_quote($chars)."])",$text)) $error .= "You can only....";
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified it to allow white spaces: `([^a-zA-Z0-9_ ` (for newbies: an underscore and a space after the 9)

Comment: How about my comment: "it would be better to allow other letters as well, like Ł,ß,å etc." Do you have an idea?

Comment: I commented in reply to your comment.

Comment: OK. Then I guess I handle character coding the wrong way. The text must be 30 chars or less but when I type certain special characters, the length of the text becomes more (e.g. ` becomes â€™)